# How to perform inverse in GF(2) and multiply in GF(256) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, communication, linear-algebra, galois-field

I have a binary matrix  `A` (only `1` and `0`), and a vector `D` in Galois field (256). The vector `C` is calculated as:

```
  C = (A^^-1)*D
```

where `A^^-1` denotes the inverse matrix of matrix `A` in `GF(2)`, `*` is multiply operation. The result vector `C` must be in `GF(256)`. I tried to do it in Matlab.

```
A= [ 1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0;
     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0;
     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0;
     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0;
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     0;
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0;
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1;
     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0;
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0;
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0;
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0]

D=[0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;103;198;105;115]
A=gf(A,1);
D=gf(D,8); %%2^8=256
C=inv(A)*D
%% The corrected result must be
%%C=[103;187;125;210;181;220;161;20;175;175;187;187;220;115]
```

However, for above code, I cannot achieved as my expected result

```
C=[103;187;125;210;181;220;161;20;175;175;187;187;220;115]
```

It produces an error as

```
Error using  *  (line 14)
Orders must match.
```

Could you help me achieve my expected result?

Comment: Note: this has nothign to do with the inverse, just wih the multiplication. If you change your code to `invA=inv(A); C=invA*D` the error will be in the last line.

Comment: @AnderBiguri The error is in the last line anyway. The error in the OP's post should read `using *` for the code in the question. The use of .* and * does not affect the final result or the production of an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error

> Error using  *  (line 14)
>   Orders must match.

arises because Matlab does not support applying standard mathematical operations (`+`, `*`, `.*`, `.^`, `\`, etc.) to Galois Fields of different order, `GF(2)` and `GF(256)`. The inverse operation, `inv(A)` is a valid operation and if you perform it on its own as [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527625/how-to-perform-inverse-in-gf2-and-multiply-in-gf256-in-matlab#comment54838305_33527625) by @[Ander Biguri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485872/ander-biguri) it will succeed and generate the inverse of `A` in `GF(2)`. Your calculation breaks down when you attempt to multiply `inv(A)` and `D` as the orders of these Galois Fields do not match.

In this example it is unnecessary to explicitly define `A` as a Galois Field of order 2, `GF(2)` as multiplication in `GF(256)` takes place in `GF(2)`. That is `1 + 1 = 0`.

If we thus modify the code that creates the Galois Field for `A` to

```
A = gf(A, 8);
```

we can then perform

```
C = inv(A)*D
```

which produces

```
C = GF(2^8) array. Primitive polynomial = D^8+D^4+D^3+D^2+1 (285 decimal)

Array elements = 

         103
         187
         125
         210
         181
         220
         161
          20
         175
         175
         187
         187
         220
         115
```

`C` is thus in `GF(256)` and produces the expected result.

Comment: Thank IKavanagh, Sorry about my late to reply. It is really good answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is either

A) a theoretical fault in your computation or

B) something that MATLAB doesn't support.

As per the documentation in [Galois field arithmetic](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/error-detection-and-correction.html#fp6358) (emphasis mine):

> Section Overview.  You can perform arithmetic operations on Galois
>   arrays by using familiar MATLAB operators, listed in the table below.
>   **Whenever you operate on a pair of Galois arrays, both arrays must be**
>   **in the same Galois field.**

And your matrices aren't.

I cant know which one is it as I have no idea how Galois fields work