# How to solve linear algebra equation AC=D where A is non-square matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, signal-processing, linear-algebra, equation

I have a binary matrix  A (only 1 and 0), and a vector D in Galois field (256)  The vector C is calculated as:

```
  C = (A^^-1)*D
```

where A^^-1 denotes the inverse matrix of matrix A in GF(2), * is multiplication operation. The result vector C must be in GF(256).

However, I only have a matrix A1 is non-square matrix. The above matrix A in the equation is created by delete some dependence rows of A1. In same manner, the vector D is constructed by delete some element corresponding the deleted rows in A1. Hence, we can solve above equation. My question is that can we have any function in MATLAB to do above steps?

For example, I have A1 is 16x14 matrix, D1 is 16x1 vector

```
A1 =[1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1 ]

D1=[0; 0; 0;  0 ; 0;   0 ;  0;   0 ;  0 ;  0 ;  103 ;  198 ;  105 ;  115;   175  ;  14]
```

In above example, we need to delete two dependence rows/cols from A1 to obtain A is 14x14 matrix and D1 also delete 2 elements to obtain D, and then my expected result is

```
C=A^^-1*D
C= [  103;   187 ;  125;   210 ;  181;   220 ;  161   ; 20 ;  175;   175;  187;   187 ;  220 ;  115]
```

This is what I tried

```
%%A1=gf(A1,8);
%%D1=gf(D1,8); %%2^8=256
%% Do something and last step is
%%C=inv(A)*D
[C,vld] = gflineq(A1,D1,8)
Or 
C=gf(A1,8) \ gf(D1,8)
```

However, these ways did not return the my expected C vector. I found that Gaussian Elimination can be worked, but I don't know how can I apply for my case. Could you give me a correct solution?

Comment: it does not work for Galois field matrix

Comment: I think that matlab will support some function to solve above problem. In general case, I found that Gaussian Elimination can be do it. But for my problem, I don't see any way for it

Comment: I have *no idea* what any of this Galois field stuff is... but if this were normal linear algebra, it sounds like you're possibly asking for something like `C = (A1'*A1)\(A1'*D1)` or equivalently `C = inv(A1'*A1)*(A1'*D1)`? That's the solution in a least squares sense to an overdetermined system. Good chance though I'm completely off base.

Comment: @MatthewGunn: No, It is not correct. I have A1 and D1. By some way to remove dependence rows/cols in A1, I have a independence A and D (D is constructed by remove positions similar in A1), I will have A, D and apply A^^-1*D, I can obtain C

Comment: How about `C=A1\D1`? That's what [docs appear to say here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/error-detection-and-correction.html#fp6410)?

Comment: It is not work. Could you tried with my above data. I think the function http://kr.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/gflineq.html is more suitable, but it still not work for GF(8)

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you get any error? Or does it just not give you a solution? Or a wrong solution? Or something not in GF(256)?

Comment: I cannot find the solution as C.

Comment: The ouput must be C= [  103;   187 ;  125;   210 ;  181;   220 ;  161   ; 20 ;  175;   175;  187;   187 ;  220 ;  115]

Comment: What is the output of `C=A1\D1`?

Comment: Sir, If I work in GF(256), then C=A1\D1, is not correct. You can tried with above example

Comment: Does my answer on [How to perform inverse in GF(2) and multiply in GF(256) in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527625/how-to-perform-inverse-in-gf2-and-multiply-in-gf256-in-matlab) work for you? At a quick glance this looks like an identical question.

Comment: Hello IKavanagh again, This question is  for encoding part. I am working in decoding which A is nonsquare matrix. To solve it, general way looks like gaussian elimination will be work.

Comment: @user3051460 Sorry I don't understand. I've not looked at this too in-depth versus the previous as I don't have much time. What is the difference between the 2 questions and the specific error/issue you have? Its not clear from the question.

Comment: Yes, I will explain in shortly. The equation C=A^^-1*D is similar with your ans. However, in here I have a new matrix A1 which created from A with some combination of row and cols, so A1 is dependence matrix. We must remove two cols or rows to create a independence matrix A, then we can apply the inv(A) .

Comment: This is one example in Example: Solving Linear Equations.  http://kr.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/error-detection-and-correction.html#fp6410

Comment: Do you tried it with GF(256)?My target is GF(256), not GF(2)

Comment: See my edited answer if you want to see what's going on. It works now, had to redefine sum in GF(2^8) as I don't have access to the toolbox

Comment: Are you trying to do some error detection and correction scheme?  Is matrix `A` the syndrome?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I am using a error correction for channel coding. The name is Raptor FEC . You can see it at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5053

Comment: Well, the algorithm is described right there is the RFC

Comment: Yes, sir. Do you have any idea for that standard. I read it so long time but I did not understand all details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I don't have access to the "Communication system toolbox", so in order to operate in `GF(2)` I have to add `mod(stuff,2)` calls in the code, and in order to operate in `GF(2^8)` I had to implement a function that sums in this field. Just define your variables with `gf` and remove these calls if you have access to the toolbox.

Prerequisite : Summing in `GF(2^8)` :

Summing in `GF(2^8)` is not trivial, as it behaves like `(Z/2Z)^8`.
In order to sum in this field, I have the following function.

Basically, elements in `GF(2^8)` are 8-tuples, each element taking a value in `{0,1}`. For example, `(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0)` is one of them. In order to sum two tuples in this field, ones has, for each element to take the sum in `Z/2Z`.
For example, if we want the sum of `(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)` and `(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)` : (Remember that in `Z/2Z`, `0+0=0` , `0+1=1` , `1+0=1` and `1+1=0`)

First elements of these tuple are `0` and `1`, so the first element of the sum will be `0+1=1`. Do this with all elements and you obtain :

`(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)+(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)=(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0)`

The function operates the same way :

**1) Transform inputs into binary numbers**

**2) Compare each digit. If they're equal they sum up to `0 (0+0=0 , 1+1=0)`, if not they sum up to `1 (0+1=1 and 1+0=1)`.**

**3) Transform result back into decimal numbers**

```
function [D] = SumInGF256(D1,D2)
%UNTITLED3 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here


A=size(D1);
P=numel(D1);
D=zeros(A);

D1=dec2bin(D1,8);
D2=dec2bin(D2,8);

% TmpD=cell(A);

for jj=1:P

    TmpD1=D1(jj,:);
    TmpD2=D2(jj,:);



    out='';

    for ii=1:8

        if isequal(TmpD1(ii),TmpD2(ii))

            out=strcat(out,'0');

        else

            out=strcat(out,'1');

        end    


    end

    D(jj)=bin2dec(out);

end
```

Gaussian elimination in GF(2) works exactly the same way in essance than in R or C, except it's much easier due to the fact that `1+1=0`. Here's the code :

```
A1 =[1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;...
     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;...
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;...
     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0;...
     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0;...
     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0;...
     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0;...
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     0;...
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0;...
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1;...
     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0;...
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0;...
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0;...
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;...
     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0;...
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1 ];


D1=[0; 0; 0;  0 ; 0;   0 ;  0;   0 ;  0 ;  0 ;  103 ;  198 ;  105 ;  115;   175  ;  14];





for ii=1:14

   % Find ii-th pivot index between row ii and last row
   PivIndex=find(A1(ii:end,ii),1)+ii-1;

   % Switch ii-th row with Pivot row
   A1([ii PivIndex],:)=A1([PivIndex ii],:);
   D1([ii PivIndex])=D1([PivIndex ii]);

   % Find all rows other than row ii containing a 1 in column ii
   RowIndexes=find(A1(:,ii));
   RowIndexes(RowIndexes==ii)==[];

   % Add row ii to all rows in RowIndexes, do the same in D
   A1(RowIndexes,:)=mod(A1(RowIndexes,:)+repmat(A1(ii,:),numel(RowIndexes),1),2);

%% Problem with my answer was here, as the sum in GF(256) doesn t work like that. (GF(256),+) behaves like ((Z/2Z)^8,+)... See prequisite for summing in GF(256)

   % D1(RowIndexes)=mod(D1(RowIndexes)+repmat(D1(ii),numel(RowIndexes),1),256);

   D1(RowIndexes)=SumInGF256(D1(RowIndexes),repmat(D1(ii),numel(RowIndexes),1));

end

% Now A1 is diagonal, with both last rows being zero. Problem is D
% has to be 0 aswell on the 2 last positions to get 0=0..
% Check if D(15:16)==[0;0] if not the system has no solution

if isequal(D1(15:16),[0;0])

A2=A1(1:14,:);
C=D1(1:14)


else

    disp('No solution')

end
```

Here the output is as you wanted :

> C =
>
> 103    187    125    210    181    220    161
>       20    175    175    187    187    220    115

Comment: No. It is not correct. I was succesful. I will give the ans.

Comment: Can't wait to see it

Comment: You're gonna have to explain, though, how you find a map GF(2)xGF(256)-->GF(256) that maps (0,x) to 222 .....

Comment: I ans. it. Let check it

Comment: Sorry my late. Thank it. It is good explaination

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like thank BillBokeey for your work. However, I am working in GF(256), it is more complex than GF(2). After google, I find a good solution for my case. This is source code for [rfc-6330](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40554-rfc6330-fec-code). In that source code, he had a function that is rfc6330_gaussian. For my question above, it is easy to apply it by

`C=rfc6330_gaussian( A1, D1 )`

So the result will be similar my expected result

```
C=[ 103
   187
   125
   210
   181
   220
   161
    20
   175
   175
   187
   187
   220
   115]
```

This ans. will be useful for anyone who has similar my issue.

Comment: Did you read the doc?

Comment: `A is converted using Gaussian elimination (using row operations and row and column reorderings) and after discarding M - L rows, into the L x L identity matrix.`

Comment: They don't check if a solution exists

Comment: They discard rows and then calculate what 'Would be the solution if these rows wouldn't have been there in the first place'

Comment: I'm sure they find solutions to `x+y=1 ; x+y=2`

Comment: Yes, it is gaussian elimination but for GF(256), not for GF(2). As your case, GF(2) is not work

Comment: "A is converted using Gaussian elimination (using row operations and row and column reorderings) and after discarding M - L rows, into the L x L identity matrix. " similar proceduce what I explained in my question

Comment: Try running `C=rfc6330_gaussian([1 1;1 1],[1;2])` , i'm interested in the result

Comment: `0` Like in "the answer is 0" or like "Error"?

Comment: SOrry, I did not post all output . The output is Decoding failed in Gaussian Elimination!

C =

     0

Comment: I don't think this is the mathematically correct answer to your question. It solves your problem and gives the answer you expect though.

Comment: Exactly my point @IKavanagh . How is the mapping between GF(2^8) and 1:256 defined btw? Normally `(GF(2^8),+)` should behave like `(Z/2Z)^8` and not like `(Z/256Z)`

Comment: Oh wait, binary writing...

Comment: Welcome a new ans with good explaination.

Comment: @user3051460 Check edited answer